# jquery ui autocomplete and json call

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete for a textbox using the following code, but it's not working:
(The ajax call to MyUrl works fine and returns a json string made of List of strings)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchbox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/MyUrl/" + request.term.toLowerCase(),
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            });

        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Is this call correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to `return` the data, you're supposed to pass it to the `response` callback.

```
success: function(data) {
    response(data);
}
```

Which is pretty much the same thing as:

```
success: response
```